# My output is too long and it takes time to wait for the result(python)

Tags: python, string

I need to find all possible combinations for the strings that I input. The length of the strings is required to be more than 10, and the combinations cannot repeat.

My code works fine with strings under 10 but it takes quite some time to wait for the result otherwise. If the string is over 15, the compiler shows a "memory error."

Here is my code:

```
def str_replace(str, x, y):
    if x == y:
        return str
    x_val = str[x:x+1]
    y_val = str[y:y+1]
    if x < y:
        str = str[0:x] + y_val + str[x+1:y] + x_val + str[y+1:len(str)]
    else:
        str = str[0:y] + x_val + str[y+1:x] + y_val + str[x+1:len(str)]
    return str

def str_sort(str,x):

    if x == len(str):               
        global str_list
        str_list.append(str)
        return
    for i in range(x,len(str)):
        if str[i] not in str[x:i]:
            str = str_replace(str,i,x)  
            str_sort(str,x+1)
            str = str_replace(str,x,i)  
        else:
            return
s = input("Input string：")
global str_list
str_list = []
str_sort(s,0)


print(*str_list,sep='\n')
print ('Total combinations：',len(str_list))
```

Is there any better code to run this program, or is it just the RAM problem?

Comment: Have you calculated how many different strings you're creating? This is a combinatorial explosion.

Comment: One thing here, don't reassign `str`. It's a builtin class, not sure if that's what causes this issue tho

Comment: at the end of the program, it will show how many strings I've created.

Comment: I will try to avoid the str problem and see if it is the case

Comment: But it doesn't get to the end of the program. You should calculate it mathematically using the combinations formula. You'll find out that it grows more than exponentially with the size of the input. Combinations grow factorially.

Comment: It comes to an end finally, yep its probably the size of the input that affects it

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any better code to run this program

Yes, using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) which is implemented in C. Instead of computing all the permutations at once and storing them in a list, they are generated once at a time during each iteration, so the memory footprint is tiny.

Note though that your console probably won't be able to display all the permutations at once. With a long enough string, it probably won't even ever finish printing the strings.

```py
s = input('Input string：')
for permutation in itertools.permutations(s):
    print(''.join(permutation))

print('Total combinations：', math.factorial(len(s)))
```

> or is it just the RAM problem?

Yes, as *Barmar* mentioned, permutations grow factorially, and you are trying to store all of those strings in memory.

A string of 15 characters has 1307674368000 permutations - `math.factorial(15)`

A string with 15 characters consumes 64 bytes - `sys.getsizeof("a"*15)`

Each element of a large list consumes ~8 bytes - `sys.getsizeof([""]*10**6) / 10**6`

So your `str_list` would consume 87686.46766037178 GiB of memory. Your computer probably only has 32 GiB of RAM.